# Outlook over VPN unbelievably slow, are there configurations that will help?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vpn, search, performance

My wife uses a CISCO VPN + Outlook 2010 + Windows 7 64 bit to connect to work from home.  Her outlook application grinds to a halt for several minutes whenever she searches her inbox.

However, if she logs in to a work machine using VNC, the same search takes only a few seconds... suggesting some portion of the network connection (including the VPN component) is the cause.

Are there simple tricks that can speed things up? Or perhaps alternative work flow suggestions?  We recently upgraded from Windows XP and Outlook 2003 where the same problem was evident.

-Setjmp

Comment: i think its becuase its searching the mailbox on the server rather than locally - have you tried cached mode? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179175.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved when we configured outlook for "Cached Exchange Mode" in the server settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving everything out of the main Inbox folder into subfolders.  Outlook seems to generate a lot of I/O for messages in the root Inbox folder for some reason.

Comment: Or this might be a nice reason to start using the Inbox Zero principle. :-)

Comment: Inbox Zero seems to be some sort of GTD ripoff.